# Equivalent of Workspace.Get with the Azure DevOps Client Libraries

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am porting legacy code that is using the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client libraries to .NET 6 using the new client libraries ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)).

I cannot work out what I need to do to mimic a simple "Get" operation.

With the old libraries, a project collection is created, a workspace mapped and then a full recursive get could be called for any path.

With the new libraries, the closest I can get is to obtain a TfvcHttpClient and call GetItemsAsync.  But I can only specify one level of recursion and the call doesn't download the files.

I have been all over the client samples [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples) but they only show how to enumerate through a list of items.  I can't see anything that actually gets any source?  The repo has been marked as read only now so I can't ask questions there.

Is there no way with the new client libraries of doing what was possible before i.e. the "get" of a source control folder with full recursion?

Can anyone point me in the direction of a sample that performs actual retrieval of source?

Answer (score 0):

After you have obtained the list of items with [`GetItemsAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvchttpclientbase.getitemsasync) you retrieve their contents one by one with [`GetItemAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvchttpclientbase.getitemasync) on each of the source paths of those items, obtained from its `Path` property.